# msg.exe prints "Invalid parameter(s)"

Tags: windows, powershell, messagebox

I am working on a small server monitoring script, and want to show a pop-up window to the user with a list of services once they are detected to be down. I tried sending this message with `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msg.exe` but it just gives me a mysterious error message in the PowerShell terminal ("Invalid parameter(s)", I thought I maybe had special characters or bad data types, but that is not the case):

```
PS U:\> msg * ("A" * 256)
```

```
Invalid parameter(s)
Send a message to a user.

MSG {username | sessionname | sessionid | @filename | *}
    [/SERVER:servername] [/TIME:seconds] [/V] [/W] [message]
```

Answer (score 3):

`msg.exe` apparently only supports messages <= 255 characters in length. Use [`Popup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/x83z1d9f(v=vs.84)) instead:

```
(New-Object -ComObject "Wscript.Shell").Popup("Popup Message", 0, "Popup Title", 0+48)
```